BER curve versus SNR for using matched filter receiver
I want to simulate matched filter receiver with rectangular pulse shape in an AWGN channel. My goal is to plot the BER curve versus SNR for BPSK modulation. I have written the code and my curve is as follows:

It seems to me that the performance of the system is too good and is beyond the capacity and the performance of the system should be a little worse. I think there is a problem with my simulation.

well, what's the energy of your matched filter? This seems to be the old case where one might be confusing looking at an Eb/N0 curve vs looking at an SNR curve. What matters to the bit error rate is how much noise there is relative to signal at the decider, not on the channel.
